# calculation field in gravity form

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I created an online application form with gravity form plugin for my WordPress website, which applicants may come and fill their information. I want to create a "score" hidden field that calculates each applicant's total score. for example if they choose their university degree from a combo box, they get different points for bachelor, masters, PhD etc. or different score for years of experience. how can I use java script to change total score field based on different choices or entries?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Product`, `Option` and `Total`fields. If they suit your needs, then you won't need Javascript at all.